# React vite app SSL and Proxy error after uploading express backend to server

Tags: reactjs, express, ssl, proxy, vite

**I've uploaded my express server code to `vercel` everything is ok on server my in my react application showing this error**

```
>  error when starting dev server: TypeError: Cannot create property
> 'prependPath' on boolean 'true'
>     at new ProxyServer (file:///C:/Users/ThinkPad/Desktop/truthgate-social-media-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-9A4-l-43.js:58830:24)
>     at Function.createProxyServer (file:///C:/Users/ThinkPad/Desktop/truthgate-social-media-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-9A4-l-43.js:58975:10)
>     at file:///C:/Users/ThinkPad/Desktop/truthgate-social-media-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-9A4-l-43.js:59019:35 
>     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
>     at proxyMiddleware (file:///C:/Users/ThinkPad/Desktop/truthgate-social-media-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-9A4-l-43.js:59011:26)
>     at _createServer (file:///C:/Users/ThinkPad/Desktop/truthgate-social-media-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-9A4-l-43.js:60607:25)
>     at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/ThinkPad/Desktop/truthgate-social-media-app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:764:24)
```

**my vite config file**

> import { defineConfig } from 'vite' import react from
> '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
>
> // https://vitejs.dev/config/ export default defineConfig({   plugins:
> [react()],
>
> resolve: {
> alias: [
> { find: '@', replacement: '/src' }
> ],   },   // ...
>
> server: {
> port: 3000,
> proxy: {
> "/api": { target: "https://truthgate-backend.vercel.app" },
> secure: true
> }   },
>
> })

**my backend `index.js`**

> import express from 'express'; import connectDB from
> './DB/connectDB.js'; import dotenv from 'dotenv'; import postRouter
> from './routes/postRoute.js'; import userRouter from
> './routes/userRoute.js'; import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
> import cors from 'cors'; import { v2 as cloudinary } from
> 'cloudinary';
>
> dotenv.config(); const app = express(); const port = process.env.PORT
> || 3000;
>
> (async () => {
> try {
> await connectDB();
>
> ```
>     app.use(express.json({ limit: "30mb" }));
>     app.use(cookieParser());
>     app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
>     cloudinary.config({
>         cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
>         api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
>         api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET,
>     })
>
>     // Adjust CORS settings based on your production requirements
>     app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true }));
>
>     // Routes (Ensure your routes don't need the /api/v1 prefix again)
>     app.use("/api/v1", postRouter);
>     app.use("/api/v1", userRouter);
>
>     app.listen(port, () => {
>         console.log(`App is running on port ${port}`);
>     });
> } catch (error) {
>     console.error("Error starting the server:", error);
>     // Handle initialization errors gracefully
> } })();
> ```

**Note: i've updated node js to the latest version**